# Soft keyboard in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard

I have `ViewPager`, and couple of pages that contain `EditText` fields. The task is to open soft keyboard on page with first `EditText` (phone number), after click on Done button switch to another page and set focus on second `EditText`(verification code). Keyboard must be always opened, `EditText` field must be above. On second page it got covered.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/verification"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/superup_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="33%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="65%"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/animated_superup_logo_white"/>

    <superup.onboarding.NonSwipeableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/verifyPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/transition">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/superup_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="67%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/superup_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/superup_name"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/layout_start_text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/layout_number_text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="3%"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent="23%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="75%">

                <superup.onboarding.CountryCodePicker
                    android:id="@+id/country_code"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:contentColor="@color/white"
                    app:countryPreference="IL"
                    app:defaultNameCode="IL"
                    app:hideNameCode="true"
                    app:textSize="24sp"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:digits="1234567890"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_otp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <superup.onboarding.PinEntryEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_code"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:digits="1234567890"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent="23%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="20%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="20%"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_wrong"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/et_code"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/wrong_number"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txt_wrong"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    </superup.onboarding.NonSwipeableViewPager>

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

With page swipe it works perfect, but i need to switch pages with keyboard. After changing page with `verifyPager.setCurrentItem`, `EditText` is covered with keyboard over it.

```
et_number.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            switch (actionId) {
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                    verifyPager.setCurrentItem(verifyPager.getChildCount() - 1);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Samsung with Android 6 has this bug, Nexus 5X/6P/Asus don't.

Answer (score 1):

I think this your `First EditText`

```
 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:digits="1234567890"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>
```

and this is `Second`

```
<superup.onboarding.PinEntryEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_code"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:digits="1234567890"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent="23%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="20%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="20%"/>
```

just give the `id of Second to First one` like below way.

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_code"
```

write above code in the `First EditText`.